# java database connection confusion

Tags: java

I was some practice code from Big Java 4th on connecting my program to a derby database. I get the following every time though.

`Usage: java -classpath driver_class_path;. TestDB database.properties` as the output and I can't figure out why it won't connect.

This is my test database:

```
public class TestDB 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {   
   if (args.length == 0)
    {   
     System.out.println(
           "Usage: java -classpath driver_class_path" 
           + File.pathSeparator 
           + ". TestDB database.properties");
     return;
  }
  else 
     SimpleDataSource.init(args[0]); `

  Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
  try
  {
     Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

     stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Test (Name CHAR(20))");
     stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Romeo')");

     ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");
     result.next();
     System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));

     stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
  }
  finally
  {
     conn.close();
  }
   }
 }
```

This is the connection program supplied:

```
  public class SimpleDataSource
 {
  private static String url;
  private static String username;
  private static String password;

    /**
      Initializes the data source.
      @param fileName the name of the property file that 
      contains the database driver, URL, username, and password
    */
   public static void init(String fileName)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
   {  
  Properties props = new Properties();
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  props.load(in);

  String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
  url = props.getProperty("jdbc:url");
  username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
  if (username == null) username = "";
  password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
  if (password == null) password = "";
  if (driver != null)
     Class.forName(driver);
   }

   /**
    Gets a connection to the database.
    @return the database connection
   */
   public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
   {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `usage` method is telling you how to run the program correctly. Let me translate that into English, in case for some reason the place where you got this code from doesn't explain it.

> Usage:

Here we are going to show how to use the program from a command prompt. If running the program from an IDE it would be similar but you would omit "java" and the classpath and program name would be configured separately.

> java

The command to run Java programs

> -classpath driver_class_path;.

specifying your classpath as the location of the Derby driver, and then the current directory (where your program lives)

> TestDB

The name of your program - which is TestDB, so don't change this

> database.properties

The filename of the properties file to use. The properties file contains the database connection parameters. This is a software development good practice! The database password, if any, must match the password you have set up.